# Difference between sqldf and rmysql?

Tags: r, rmysql, sqldf

[sqldf](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) and [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf) are both R packages that allow access to a MySQL database (the former using the latter). They both allow statements like this:

RMySQL: "Run an arbitrary SQL statement and extract all its output (returns a data.frame):"

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) from a_table")
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from a_table")
```

sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from iris limit 5")
sqldf("select count(*) from iris")
sqldf("select Species, count(*) from iris group by Species")
# create a data frame
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
```

So what are the differences? What does sqldf offer that RMySQL doesn't?

Comment: `sqldf` allows you to issue SQL statements against data frames.

Comment: Meaning, doing SQL analysis on data that came from anywhere (possibly not an SQL database)?

Comment: If you're interested in connecting to a MySQL data base from R, stick with RMySQL (or RODBC).

Comment: sqldf manipulates data frames in your workspace by connecting to a backend database using RMySQL (or RSQLite, RH2 or RPostgreSQL) -- the default is RSQLite.  If the source of your data is a data frame in your R workspace then you would use sqldf. If the source of your data is in a MySQL database then you would use RMySQL directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sqldf` is used to issue SQL statements, and have them act on data frames.  `iris` is not a database table, but a built-in data set.

```
> head(iris, n=3)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

`sqldf` is not used to connect to databases.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the observation by Lundberg that dataframes are acceptable targets for SQL-commands, there is also the point that `sqldf` can go against any (disk-resident) table in SQLite (the default), H2, MySQL, or postgresSQL: https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/